# Час между волком и собакой

Tags: этимология, фразеология, значение-слов

Есть такое определение времени: **час между волком и собакой.**
Насколько я знаю, это очень раннее утро, рассвет. Но интересно было бы знать, **почему** это время так называется?
И собака, и волк — животные, так сказать, "круглосуточные", у них нет явно выраженного времени сна и бодрствования (особенно у собак, которые вынуждены приспосабливаться к людям), таким образом, нельзя сказать, что в это время волк уступает свою активность собаке.
Тогда с чем же связан такой образ?

Comment: Час, когда волк и собака (пастушеская, овчарка, т. е. тот же волк) неотличимы.

Comment: Если между собакой и волком, то вечерние сумерки. А если между волком и собакой, то предрассветное время.

Answer (score 2):

**Пора меж волка и собаки** (кроме как у Пушкина, мне этот фразеологизм в русском языке не попадался) означает сумерки. В русском языке выражение появилось путем буквального перевода с французского, тот — с латинского, а как появилось там — неизвестно.
То ли это время, когда собаку можно спутать с волком; то ли есть легенда, где пастух их все-таки спутал; то ли собака здесь выступает дневным животным, а волк — ночным.
Доподлинно неизвестно.

Comment: Мне нравится последняя версия. Остальное все ха уши (собачьи) притянуто, имхо. Хотя, кто их, французов латинских, поймет, конечно, но не настолько же, чтобы волка с собакой путать, даже ночью.

Answer (score 0):

> Пора меж волка и собаки...
>
> ***В этом стихе некоторые находили - ошибочно - объяснение слову: entre chien et loup; смысл его, однако, другой: это промежуток
>   времени, когда надо выпустить сторожевых собак, так как вслед за ним
>   из леса появятся волки.***...

(Словарь Михельсона, цитирую отсюда:
http://enc-dic.com/michelson/Pora-mezh-volka-i-sobaki-8186.html
Курсив мой, b-s.)

Здесь дается (наряду еще с несколькими) вполне естественное объяснение. И да, собака здесь вполне дневное, домашнее животное, волк - ночное и дикое.

Answer (score 0):

> Но интересно было бы знать, почему это время так называется? И собака,
>   и волк - животные, так сказать, круглосуточные, у них нет явно
>   выраженного время сна и бодрствования

Вероятно, римляне были другого мнения. 
Это именно сумерки, правда изначально, видимо вечерние, возможно потом потом уже, потеряв связь с исходным значением, распространилось и на предрассветные часы.

Зря удалили ответ user181982.
Там почти все правильно и достаточно аргументировано.

Вот как объясняет это латинское выражение фарлексовский словарь
http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Inter+canem+et+lupum

INTER CANEM ET LUPUM. Literally, between the dog and the wolf. Metaphorically, the twilight; because then the dog seeks his rest, and the wolf his prey.

То есть это сумерки (вероятно - ранние вечерние), "когда собака ищет отдых, а волк - добычу".

Comment: Не ранние вечерние, а предутренние, сгустившаяся тьма перед восходом.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Вы про Пушкина или про римлян? Впрочем, в обоих случаях - неверно. Именно вечерние. Смотрите источник по ссылке. А насчет Пушкина - утренние не получаются по смыслу. Ну кто ж утром-то с друзьями будет вино пить?

Answer (score 0):

**Пора меж волка и собаки**

*Lorsqu’il n’est jour ne nuit, quand le vaillent berger*
*Si c’est un chien ou loup ne peut juger.*
Baif. XIII s.

"Въ этомъ стихѣ нѣкоторые находили, ошибочно, объясненіе слову: entre chien et loup; смыслъ его однако другой: это промежутокъ времени, когда надо выпустить сторожевыхъ собакъ, такъ какъ вслѣдъ за нимъ изъ лѣса появятся волки".

Ср. *Inter canem et lupum.*
Ср. *Dubia luce. Sideris dubiis — въ сумерки.*

Пер.: сумерки — не отличить волка отъ собаки.

**[источник](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_old/7165/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)**

---

**Вопрос:**
Что есть "час волка", когда он был и почему так назван? Внимательно читал Ваш ответ, а на этом "часе" "споткнулся".
Разъясните, пожалуйста, а?

**Ответ:**
"В неврологии есть такое неофициальное название, как «час волка».
Под «часом волка» называют промежуток времени с 4 до 5 утра, в который максимальны проявления депрессии. По всей видимости, именно в это время происходит истощение многих «защитных» нейромедиаторных систем мозга. Именно в это время пациенты с депрессией могут просыпаться (в отличие от диссомнии другого генеза, при которой нет временных закономерностей), именно в это время проявляются различные соматизированные жалобы больных.

Проводя расспрос пациентов, можно выявить тот факт, что утром (не только в «час волка») человек чувствует себя мучительно, им овладевает усталость и снижение энергии. Также любопытен тот статистически доказанный факт, что именно в «час волка» происходит наибольшее количество самоубийств".

---

Час волка - Kinopoisk.Ru:

"Художник в разговоре со своей супругой упоминает, что «час волка» — это время между тремя и четырьмя часами утра, когда вся на свете нечисть оживает... Час волка — это сумасшествие, это проникновение в разум художника..."

---

"Часом волка называют час перед рассветом".

---

Это всё легко гуглится.

Но самое авторитетное определение времени (вопрос о точности остаётся недопрояснённым) — у невролога и Бергмана.

**[источник](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1962357-pochemu-ljudi-polzujutsja-voprosnikom-na-majl-esli-tam-ne-platjat-deneg-za-eto.html#answer5819880)**

Comment: *это промежутокъ времени, когда надо выпустить сторожевыхъ собакъ, такъ какъ вслѣдъ за нимъ изъ лѣса появятся волки.* - так почему утренние-то? Гуглите нормально, правдоподобные источники..

Comment: Первая цитата  - для общего развития. Все последующие разъясняют, какой именно час признан часом волка. Собака же приходит на смену волку? Значит, речь о раннем утре.

Comment: У Пушкина - да. Но у французов и латынян - наоборот. О том и речь. Пушкин мог не вкладывать такого смысла, тем более что сидеть с друзьями утром - противоестественно. А все Ваши "источники" начисто  игнорируют перевоисточник. И вообще, передайте этому психиатру, что "часом Волка" в Москве при Горбачеве в своё время называли 2 часа дня, о чем сообщал кукольный волк на часах театра Образцова и открывались водочные магазины. Да вот ни Пушкин, ни Гораций о том не знали.

Comment: А что у нас первоисточник? В вопросе - что это за сомнительное противопоставление двух схожих зверюшек. А о театре такое: "В советское время так окрестили 11 часов - время начала продажи спиртного, потому что часовая стрелка часов на театре Образцова как раз подползала к изображению волка".

Comment: У вас - не знаю, у меня - латинская пословица. Про Образцова - ну, да, в 11.  Я ошибся в цифре, мне почему-то запомнилось именно горбачевский период. Все равно психиатру не легче. ))))

Comment: Угу. "Ну да" не расчленяется запятой! )))

Comment: Вообще-то у меня "да" тут вводное )))). Не связанное с "ну". ))) = Ну в 11, да.

Answer (score 0):

Между волком и собакой....
Это сумеречное время, довольно короткое, когда вы видите животное, но точно определить кто это, волк или собака, не сможете. Сумерки "размывают" характерные черты.

Comment: Galina Avanesova две недели как дала к вопросу комментарий, пропустили овчарочку.